# Are there any problems if one tries to expand Internal hard drive beyond maximum capacity mentioned?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sata

I have a Sony Vaio and my laptop currently holds a 500 GB SATA hard drive. Recently the drive got crashed and I am buying a new internal Hard Drive. Let's say max capacity of my Laptop to hold is 750 GB so if I buy a 1TB drive would my laptop not support it all or it just wouldn't read beyond 750 GB and will display the net capacity as 750 GB. Apologies if this has been asked before, you can direct me to that link.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop will be able to support a bigger HDD. The MOBO doesn't care how big your HDD is, the OS cares how big it is and Windows supports the biggest HDD you can find.

Comment: I was told by the sony service center guy that I couldn't expand it beyond 750 GB.So Don't I have to first update the BIOS so that I can update upto atleast 1TB?

Comment: I guess if your laptop is old enough to not support 1TB... It came with a 750 so I didn't think it was that old. What model is the VAIO?

Comment: vpccb15fg - C Series. It came with a 500 GB internal sata hd. been 3 years since I have it. My basic query is if I install 1TB hd into my laptop will my laptop support it (I don't care as of now if the system shows 750GB or greater than that) or it will throw an error that hard drive not compatible.

Comment: You should not have any problems using a 1TB HDD in your laptop.

Out of curiosity, why did you contact Sony Support if you weren't going to take their advice?

Comment: 1TB hdd is much cheaper than 750GB, that was my main concern.